# Problema consumo de servicios desde react-native con form-data usando fetch y axios

Tags: post, react-native, fetch, axios, postman

estoy programando en react-native un app que consume servicios, cuando el servicio es consumido con POSTMAN si funciona al enviar la cabecera y el cuerpo, sin embargo cuando intento consumir con fetch y axios de react-native me devuelve status 406 no me retorna ninguna otra respuesta, no se si estoy omitiendo algo o esta algo man en mi funcion gracias [image: servicio con postman]
[image: body con postman]
[image: metodo con fetch]
[image: metodo con axios]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando `'Accept': 'application/json'` a los headers del fetch.

Comment: gracias funcionó perfectamente